# Xcode 10 cannot build project because unable to find pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode10

After cloning Xcode project from github, I opened `PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj` file with Xcode. (no Podfile is created and no pods are installed, obviously, this project does not need any pods to run).

However, after building the project, error occurs saying that:

> "error: PROJECT_DIRECTORY/Pods/Target Support
>   Files/Pods-PROJECT_NAME/Pods-PROJECT_NAME.debug.xcconfig: unable to
>   open file".

I haven't installed any pods, nor have I initialised pods in this project, because I do not need them yet.

I have tried to initialise pods in the project and installed them after what `.xcworkspace` file was created and I launched it and it have builded and run successfully.

However, I do not need any pods, so how to handle this issue without installing pods and running the project straight from `.xcodeproj` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**
`pod deintegrate` is only right approach to get rid of pods from project.

#### If you want to get it by hands:

In project settings remove configuration through pod
s xcconfig files
[image]

You may want to delete configs configs from project as well if here still reference on them:
[image]

Make sure that `Build Phases` do not contain any CocoaPods related steps:
[image]

IMHO never delete pods by hands, use `pod deintegrate`. It will remove all unnecessary files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have changed the specified values to None. Also, deleted configs from project. After building the project, Xcode gives another error: ```The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.```. However, as I stated above I do not need to install any pods. Also, I haven't installed or initialized any pods in the project previously.

Comment: @mamadnazar check build phases as in answer

Comment: There were no cocoapods related steps in Build Phases. However, it worked after ```pod deintegrate``` command. 
It turns out one pod was already installed in the project, but the changes haven't been correctly committed to git repository, from where I downloaded the project. Some of the files were missing and ```pod deintegrate``` worked perfectly in this situation. 
Thank you for your answer. Should I mark it as a correct one or should you, firstly, edit your answer so that ```pod deintegrate``` solution will be at the top